# How to find the nearest and farthest point of a conic with a given point P

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, exponential-function, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given the following equation :
$4x^2 - 9y^2 = 1$
And the point $P=(2,1)$
I have to find the nearest and farthest point of the conic with the point $P$.

What I have done:

I set $x = 1/2\cosh(t)$
and $y = 1/3\sinh(t)$

Then I calculated the squared distance $d^2 =  (x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2$
so I have the equation $f(t) = ....$ by replacing $x$ and $y$.

I got
$$f(t) = {13\over72}e^{2t} - {13\over72}e^{-2t} -{4\over3}e^t +{2\over3}e^{-t}$$
because I replaced cosh(t) as (e^t+e^-t)/2 and sinh(t) as (e^t-e^-t)/2

Then I have to find the derivate $f'(t)$ and and equate it to $0$, and I can find the maximum and minimum (if exists) of f(t.)
I got
$$f'(t) = {26\over72}e^{2t} + {26\over72}e^{-2t} -{4\over3}e^t -{2\over3}e^{-t}$$
I'm stuck at solving $f'(t) = 0$.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The farthest point doesn't exist, for a hyperbola.

Comment: The equation is a quartic: you'd better solve it with some numerical method.

Comment: The equation you have derived for $f(t)$ has several errors. When simplified, the correct $f(t)$ looks like, $$13e^{2t}+13e^{-2t}-192e^t-96e^{-t}+730.$$ Once you have worked out your $f’(t)=0$, before solving it, substitute $\space e^t=a\space$ and obtain a quartic equation in $\space a\space$. As @Intelligentipauca has stated in his $2^{\text{nd}}$ comment, you need to use an appropriate numerical method to solve it. Or you can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).